# import jupyter notebook script into a python script

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have a simple notebook script: 'test_a.ipynb' which contains a test_a() function.

test_a.ipynb is called in a python script: 'test_b.py' in the following way:

```
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', 'test_a.ipynb')
 def test_b():
    test_a()
```

The 'test_b' is then called by another python script and executed in the following way:

```
from test_b import *
test_b()
```

The error message is:

```
NameError: name 'test_a' is not defined
```

but the following script runs fine:

```
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', 'test_a.ipynb')
 def test_b():
    test_a()
 #
 test_b()
```

Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert test_b.py into a notebook script and call it using %run command in the running script:

```
 %run test_b.ipynb 
 test_b()
```

After that things works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).